# Mostrar imagen guardada en MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, imagen, blob

he logrado guardar una imagen con PHP en mi base de datos. El tipo de datos es BLOB. Hasta ahí todo correcto. Ahora bien, esto es lo que he logrado para traer mi imagen y poder verla junto a los otros datos de mi base de datos. Lo único es que la imagen se muestra rota:

[image: asi se muestra cuando traigo la imagen, rota]

ahora, este es mi código, he intentado varias cosas, pero nada:

```
<h3 class="box-title">Pagos reportados</h3>
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                                <th>NRO PEDIDO</th>
                                                <th>CEDULA</th>
                                                <th>MONTO DEL PEDIDO</th>
                                                <th>NRO.REFERENCIA</th>
                                                <th>CAPTURE</th>
                                                <th>ENTIDAD FINANCIERA</th>
                                                <th>COMENTARIO</th>
                                                <th>CAMBIAR ESTADO</th>
                                                <th>VALIDACIÓN <span class="badge badge-danger">Alerta</span></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>              

                                            <?php 
                                            $sql="SELECT * from creadas";
                                            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                                            
                                            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                            ?>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?php echo $mostrar['id_tabla'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $mostrar['npedido'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $mostrar['cedula'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $mostrar['monto'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $mostrar['referencia'] ?></td>
                                                <td>
                                                <img width="100" src="data:base64,<?php echo  base64_encode($mostrar['capture']); ?>">
                                                </td>
                                                <td><?php echo $mostrar['banco'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $mostrar['comentario'] ?></td>
```

ese es el fragemento de código, ahora si solo coloco: `<?php echo $mostrar['referencia'] ?>` me trae el nombre del archivo nada más...

**ACTUALIZACIÓN A HOY 17 DE SEPTIEMBRE DE 2020**

esto es lo que se almacena en mi tabla:

[image: datos en la tabla]

y esto es los valores de las columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

escribí este código que me sugirió ayer un usuario de la comunidad:

```
<?
```

var_dump($mostrar);
session_start();

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pedido');

$sql="SELECT * from creadas";
                                            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                                            
                                            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

header("Content-type: image/png"); echo '';

y esto fue lo que mi imprimió:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no se qué más hacer.

Comment: Intenta algo así: **`<td><img width="100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo  base64_encode($mostrar['capture']); ?>"></td>`** Queda claro que si la imagen no es `jpeg` debes cambiar ese término por la extensión adecuada. A propósito, si no lo has hecho, deberías implementar alguna estrategia para obtener el tipo (extensión) de la imagen antes de guardar el blob y poder usarlo al momento de mostrarla. Y, como consejo, evita tanta mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML, es infumable y a veces se escapan errores en tantas aperturas y cierres.

Comment: Ok, excelente, voy a probar así, ahora, si la imagen es png? como puedo obtener cualquier formato?

Comment: Tendrías que poner el `src` de este modo: `data:image/png;base64`. Como dije en mi comentario, si trabajarás con varias extensiones deberías tener una columna por cada fila que te guarde la extensión y usar dicha columna para construir la información de `data` de manera dinámica, algo así: `"data:image/$extensionObtenidaDeUnaColumna;base64"` la información sobre el tipo de archivo sería insertada al momento de crear la fila, cuando capturas y guardas el blob, debiendo determinar en ese momento de qué tipo es el archivo. Ese es tema para otra pregunta.

Comment: yo creo que me hace falta traerme ese dato, ya que coloqué el codigo como me lo mencionaste y sigue igual. Podrías responder la pregunta para lograr ver como lo estrucutro en mi codigo? saludosy gracias

Comment: Prueba que tu Blob es correcto. Sugiero que hagas una prueba simple donde obtienes el dato lanzando una consulta y muestras la imagen con un `header`, algo así: `header("Content-type: image/png");
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode( $mostrar['capture'] ) . '" />';` Crea un archivo de prueba solamente con la consulta SQL (agrégale un `LIMIT 1`para que traiga una sola fila) y ese `echo` en salida, nada de tablas, nada de etiquetas HTML, y dinos si ahí la imagen se muestra. Si no se muestra entonces o no es `png` o el blob está corrompido o se guardó mal en la BD.

Comment: ya lo hice y me imprimió esto en la pantalla: ';

Comment: ¿Qué te imprimió? ¿? Pon un `var_dump($mostrar);` y dinos qué ves en pantalla. Debes depurar los datos y también que el blob es correcto.

Comment: me muestra: '; (es decir comilla simple y un punto y coma. Coloqué el var_dump($mostrar); y sigue mostrando lo mismo.

Comment: No entiendo por qué `var_dump($mostrar);` sólo imprime un punto y coma, si en la imagen que muestras en la pregunta se ve que hay datos en `$mostrar`¿? Tienes que poner el `var_dump` dentro de un bloque PHP, no dentro de un bloque HTML.

Comment: Edita la pregunta: Toma una captura de pantalla de PhpMyAdmin donde se vea el valor de la columna _capture_ de alguno de los registros que tienes guardados y agrégala al final de la pregunta.

Comment: ya agregué los capture de todo lo que he hecho e incluso de los datos que almacenami DB y los valores de las columnas...

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he realizado de está manera, primero en la BD guardo el tipo de archivo, archivo (blob), y su nombre. Tengo una función que recibe el id del archivo que quiero descargar lo busco en la base y lo descargo.

```
public function descargarArchivo($id){
        $qry = "SELECT tipo, archivo_blob, nombre_archivo from tbl where idarchivo= ".$id;
        $res = mysql_query($qry);

        $tipo = mysql_result($res, 0, "tipo");
        $contenido = mysql_result($res, 0, "archivo_binario");
        $nombre = mysql_result($res, 0, "nombre_archivo");

         header('Content-type:'.$tipo.'');
         header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nombre.'"'); 
         echo $contenido;
    }
```

De está manera es como descargo un archivo, se que necesitas mostrar el archivo, pero puede ayudarte esta pequeña función

Comment: Excelente, me gusta la idea de descargarlo mejor, ahora bien, esta función donde la coloco, en el mismo codigo que mostré arriba? o a parte y la llamo desde adentro?